# Xamarin iOS: how to keep the view active when the loading logo in on the screen

Tags: ios, xamarin, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, xamarin.ios

In my iOS project, the page has a list view which takes some time to load. I want to display the loading squiggly as shown [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/) but it is disabling the whole page until it loads up. I want to let the user go back using the navigation button if they want to during the loading process.

The code I am using now is:

```
var bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds; 
loadPop = new LoadingOverlay (bounds);
View.Add (loadPop);
loadingOverlay.Hide ();
```

Is there any way I can let the user use navigation to switch pages while the page still displays the loading symbol and the data is still being loaded?

Comment: If you want the user to be able to navigate away, why cover the entire screen with a loading view?

Comment: Is it possible to set bound for a specific view i.e., only for list view and  giving the user chance to navigate back if choose to? If yes how can I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s very simple actually. You just need to add a view (with the spinner) on top of the list and hide it manually when data is loaded.
If you still want to use that `LoadingOverlay` sample, modify the bounds argument:

```
var navigationBarHeight = 48; // not sure what´s the actual height. Google it!
var bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds; 
loadPop = new LoadingOverlay (new CGRect(bounds.X, navigationBarHeight, bounds.Width, bounds.Height - navigationBarHeight);
View.Add (loadPop);
```

If you just need the spinner, you can also take some code from the link your provided:

```
activitySpinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge); // change color here
activitySpinner.Frame = new CGRect (
                centerX - (activitySpinner.Frame.Width / 2) ,
                centerY - activitySpinner.Frame.Height - 20 ,
                activitySpinner.Frame.Width,
                activitySpinner.Frame.Height);
activitySpinner.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
AddSubview (activitySpinner);
activitySpinner.StartAnimating ();
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to use `LoadingOverlay` sample if I don't have to. How can I just add a view (with the spinner) as you mentioned ?

Comment: @xleon The issue I am facing is that I am able to click on back button and right navigation bar button when the loading indicator is there. I wan t the loading indicator to cover the entire screen. I have used the same code provided in Xamarin docs (https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/) without subtracting the navigation bar height. Any idea why this is happening ?